# Accented characters in a dynamically generated css background-image property

Tags: javascript, html, css, apache, backbone.js

I am trying to make a dynamically generated grid of thumbnails for each member in a JSON object.

Each member has a 'title' key and value, and when the webpage loads, a URI based on the title of each member is generated.  This URI becomes the 'img' property in a backbone.js object, which is used in a template to render. (See code at the bottom).

My problem is that some of these titles have accent marks, and when the website loads, the accent marks in the thumbnail paths become "x%CC%81", where 'x' is the accented vowel. This only happens on my webserver (Apache 2.2.6) - when using MAMP (I believe it's Apache 2.2.26) to test the site locally, things work great.

I have tried to use decodeURI() when creating the string path, but to no avail. Thus, I think it has something to do with either the server (because it works in MAMP but not in my webserver), but I can't think of why. To me, the more likely culprit is the inability of CSS to parse accent marks.

Here's the snippit of backbone.js code that generates the uris for each item:

```
//For each model in the collection, generate the image uri, 
//where item.getHyphTitle() is the title that may contain accent marks

_.each(this.collection.models, function(item){
        item.set("img", decodeURI('../images/thumbs/' + item.getHyphTitle() + '-thumb.jpg'));
        renderContact(item);
 },this);
```

Here's the part of the template that is used:

```
<div class="work-background" style="background-image:url('<%= img %>');"></div>
```

I hope this is clear - ask any questions you may have to clarify. Thanks in advance for taking the time to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have an encoding error.  Some Operation Systems support what you are trying to do (I think OSX), and others do not.  Here is a link to way too much detail about the issue:

[File Systems, Unicode, and Normalization](http://developers.sun.com/global/products_platforms/solaris/reference/presentations/IUC29-FileSystems.pdf)